# Yocto Conflict between attempted installs

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have a conflict between a number of install files.

I am getting the below error:

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  612 Packages

Total size: 110 M Installed size: 403 M Downloading Packages: Running
transaction check Transaction check succeeded. Running transaction
test Error: Transaction check error:   file /etc/iproute2/rt_protos
conflicts between attempted installs of
base-files-3.0.14-r89.nexbox_a95x_s905x and iproute2-4.14.1-r0.aarch64
file /etc/iproute2/rt_tables conflicts between attempted installs of
base-files-3.0.14-r89.nexbox_a95x_s905x and iproute2-4.14.1-r0.aarch64
file /etc/sysctl.conf        conflicts between attempted installs of
base-files-3.0.14-r89.nexbox_a95x_s905x and procps-3.3.12-r0.aarch64

Error Summary
-------------

ERROR: amlogic-image-headless-sd-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed:
do_rootfs ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
/home/user/amlogic-bsp/build/tmp/work/nexbox_a95x_s905x-poky-linux/amlogic-image-headless-sd/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.29264
ERROR: Task
(/home/user/amlogic-bsp/meta-meson/recipes-core/images/amlogic-image-headless-sd.bb:do_rootfs)
failed with exit code '1' NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3131 tasks of
which 3130 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

I have seen somewhere that I should pin a file, but how do I do this? I can't find a tutorial or any reference to what that means.

I am also getting the below warning. Is this related?

```
WARNING: Layer meson should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meson in its
conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible
with.
```

I'm new to OE coming over from OpenWRT.

For bitbake, I've added the layers for the packages below:

`meta-openwrt:- OE/Yocto metadata layer for OpenWRT`

`superna9999/meta-meson:- Upstream Linux Amlogic Meson Yocto/OpenEmbedded Layer`

And tried compiling the `nexbox-a95x-s905x` image

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that  /etc/iproute2/rt_protos is provided by base-files which is coming from meta-openwrt as well as from iproute2 package which is coming from other OE layers. its not clear for the image builder which one to use and hence the conflict

You can solve it via defining a iproute2_%.bbappend file in meta-openwrt where this file gets deleted from iproute2 package and preference is given to the one openwrt provides

```
do_install_append() {
  rm -rf ${D}${sysconfdir}/iproute2/rt_protos
}
```

should help.

Comment: Thank you Khem,  I have done this but it still doesn't work. I have added the delete script to  ./meta-openwrt/recipes-tweaks/iproute2/iproute2_%.bbappend        and      ./meta-openwrt/recipes-tweaks/base-files/iproute2_%.bbappend    and    
 ./meta-openwrt/recipes-tweaks/base-files/base-files_3.%.bbappend     I have also tried changing the rm -rf ${D}${sysconfdir}/iproute2/rt_protos to  rm -rf ${STMP}/etc/iproute2/rt_protos     to see if this changes the location.      I put it in the busy-box tweak too. For good measure.

Comment: Thank you Khem, it's worked for me. I had same problem with lighttpd conf file. this is second time that you saving me.